# Was I wrong flagging this as not an answer?

Tags: discussion, flagging, not-an-answer

I'm talking about [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/316292/72179) answer which says:

> The link below explains the default rated (180VA) receptacles. [link]

I see no difference between this one and the canonical ["i think you should take The tutorial HERE"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Without the link, there is no single fact mentioned in the answer which helps the user with their question.

Have I perhaps overlooked something?

Comment: It's a self-answer.  I wonder if that made a difference.  It if were me, I would convert that answer into a comment.  Then close the question as a duplicate.  [I'll wait for Dave to chime in.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because a moderator does not ultimately affirm a flag, it does not mean that you shouldn't have raised it.

In this case, I reviewed the flag, and decided that the fact that it was a self-answer was enough of an extenuating circumstance to allow the answer to stand as-is.

Of course, any edits that improve on the answer would be welcome.

Comment: I indeed missed the fact that it was a self-answer (I've likely seen it in a review queue). I still don't think it's an answer worth keeping, but I see how bad it feels to punish a user who volunteered to share something they found helpful.

Comment: Short answers are often seen by the servers as 'low quality' and sent to a review queue to be judged by others, but flagging it as a non-answer early on can speed things up by a few days.